# Access Contact Photos - Contact ID and Photo Location mismatch

Tags: android, listview, contacts, photo

I have a ListView that I want to show contact pictures and contact names in an ImageView and TextView respectively.  I am able to generate the ListView with the contact names but am running into issues with the images.  Note:  I have read through hundreds of posts here and on the web and nothing describes the issue that I'm finding or a possible solution.

Of all the methods for accessing the photo, none of them allow you to do so using the PHOTO_URI from ContactsContract.Contacts.  All the methods involve accessing the contact _ID, using that to generate a Contact URI using ContentUris.withAppendedId and then using this to generage an InputStream, etc.

Here is my issue.  The PHOTO_URI and contact_ID are not matching.  For example:

John Smith
Contact_ID = 905
PHOTO_URI = content://com.android.contacts/contacts/270/photo

This causes almost no contact photos to even show up, in fact only 2 out of 57, and those that do show up are with the wrong contact.  That is, from the example above, John's photo shows up next to Mark because Mark's Contact_ID=270.  The other 55 contacts don't have any photo show because there are no matching photos and ID's, even though over 30 of them actually have pictures.

A secondary issue is that some PHOTO_URI's are a different path structure, such as
content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/3

I am at a complete loss here.  Here is my bindView() code in my custom adapter that is trying to access the photos.

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    //cursor is contactsCursor from FriendsContactFragment
    //{CONTACTS_ID, DISPLAY_NAME, PHOTO_URI, GROUP_ROW_ID, LOOKUP_KEY}

    //get the ViewHolder object saved in newView()
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    long contactId = cursor.getLong(0);
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

    InputStream photoData = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, contactUri);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(photoData);

    if(bm != null){
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }else{
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_friends_c);
    }

    //adding additional info to output for debugging
    viewHolder.textView.setText(cursor.getString(1) + "\nCONTACT_ID: " + cursor.getString(0) + "\nCONTACT_URI: " + contactUri + "\nPHOTO_URI: " + cursor.getString(2) + "\nphotoData: " + photoData);


}
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem at the moment. Have you found a solution to that?

Comment: I had to put this project on hold for awhile and haven't been able to pick it back up yet.  Anyhow, there was never any assistance offered here and I haven't yet solved this on my own.  If you, or anybody else has or does solve this, please fill me in! :)